# Progress Circle after pressing button till a request to an API is done

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a button in my flutter application that I want to send a request to an API after pressing it. I should wait for the process, and I want to have a progress circle that shows from the time I pressed the button until I get a response from the request. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.
Here is my onPressed code:

```
onPressed: () async {
                  Map data = {
                            //some data
                          };
                  var body = json.encode(data);
                  var response = await http.post(
                      Uri.parse("***MY API URL ***"),
                      headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "Accept": "application/json"
                      },
                      body: body);
                      // print(response.body);
                      // print(response.statusCode);
                      if (response.statusCode == 201 || response.statusCode == 200) {
                        print('success');
                        Toast.show("Success", context);
                        
                        Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => const HomePage(),
                ),
                (route) => false,
              );
                      } else {
                        Toast.show("ERROR! Please try again.", context);

                      }
                  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use like this.

Additionally if you want more `CircularProgressIndicator` customization and functions I bring here docs url
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html

There is also `LinearProgressIndicator` exists in Flutter
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/LinearProgressIndicator-class.html

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: const MyHomePage());
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: isLoading
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : TextButton(
              child: Text('Tap me'),
              onPressed: () async {
                //progress indicator start show
                setState(() => isLoading = true);

                //YOU API CALL HERE
                //await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => () {});

                //progress indicator show
                var response = await authHandler.sendPasswordResetEmail();


                //progress indicator stopped show
                setState(() => isLoading = false);
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: 2 seconds is only for show you that code waiting and don't read down till `await` keywords response come. If yo delete this line and copy your api call code here and make your api request with `await`  the end line will work when your api call is completed.

Comment: I edit some code and it will help you to understood, Thanks.